# Java Cash Register

Tags: java

I've just started doing some java, and I wanted to try out a simple cash register program that basically just calculates the change that is given back.

```
public class Customer {
    private int purchasePrice;
    private int moneyGiven;
    private int change;

    public Customer() {
        purchasePrice=0;
    }

    public Customer(int initialPurchasePrice) {
        initialPurchasePrice=purchasePrice;
    }

    public void PurchaseItem(int amount){
        purchasePrice=purchasePrice+amount;
    }

    public void MoneyGiven(int amount){
        int moneyGiven;
    }

    public int getChange(){
        int change=moneyGiven-purchasePrice;
        return change;
    }   
}

public class CustomerTester {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner (System.in);

        Customer customer1=new Customer();
        customer1.PurchaseItem(50);
        customer1.MoneyGiven(60);

        System.out.println(customer1.getChange());
    }
}
```

My output for some reason ends up being -50, when it should be 10. I think my main problem comes from the MoneyGiven constructor, but i'm not sure what to put there. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Simple and clear way of asking the question. Upvote given for that practice. :D

Answer (score 1):

First initialize your variables with default values, then change the code part to set the amount value into money given class variable.

```
private int purchasePrice=0;
private int moneyGiven=0;
private int change=0;


public void MoneyGiven(int amount){
moneyGiven= moneyGiven + amount;
}
```

Comment: it is not necessary to initalize primitive types (int, boolean, char...), because they could not be `null`. Aswell is the default value for `int` 0.

Comment: Yes Don agree on you technically. However best practice is to have initialize variables , so programmer knows this starts with ZERO value and code is descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that, in your method `moneyGiven` method, you only declare a variable and you do not set the `amount` to your variable `moneyGiven`

try something like this:

```
public void MoneyGiven(int amount){
    moneyGiven = amount;
}
```

Beside that, `MoneyGiven` is not a constructor! (Just because the first letter is uppercase, it does not mean that it is a constructor.) Constructors do not have any return value (void is a return value aswell).

You might want to rename the method to `setMoneyGiven`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem.

```
public void MoneyGiven(int amount){
        int moneyGiven;
    }
```

You are using moneyGiven global varible and in **getChange** method you are using that varible to get the change. 
what you did is you just create new method local variable and no value assign it though. 
What you need to do is assign the amount to **moneyGiven** global variable. Correct way to do it is

```
public void MoneyGiven(int amount){
        this.moneyGiven = amount;
    }
```

That will solve your issue.

PS - For best practices you also can change getChange method as below.

```
public int getChange(){
        return (moneyGiven-purchasePrice);
    }
```

or If you need to use change in some other place you can assign global variable change and return that value as below.

```
public int getChange(){
    this.change = moneyGiven-purchasePrice;
    return this.change;
}
```

this keyword is not essetial in scenarios like that. you can use variable without this keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Your moneyGiven method is wrong. It should be

```
public void MoneyGiven(int amount){
 moneyGiven = moneyGiven + amount;
}
```

and BTW your second constructor is also wrong and need to be like this:

```
public Customer( int initialPurchasePrice){
    purchasePrice = initialPurchasePrice;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method Moneygiven is the problem:
There you declare a local variable that you aren´t using. actually i guess, you missed out to put logic inside this method.

```
 public void MoneyGiven(int amount){
    int moneyGiven;
 }
```

In the end it does calculate 0-50

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of `MoneyGiven` is missing an assignment

```
public void MoneyGiven(int amount){
    int moneyGiven;
}
```

should be

```
public void MoneyGiven(int amount){
    moneyGiven = amount;
}
```

That's why `int change=moneyGiven-purchasePrice;` returns `-50` (`moneyGiven` is `0`).

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you are not assigning amount to moneyGiven. And You already had declared all variables at the beginning so just assign values to them now..

```
private int purchasePrice;
private int moneyGiven;
private int change;

public void MoneyGiven(int amount){
int moneyGiven; // redeclaring 
}

public int getChange(){

    int change=moneyGiven-purchasePrice; // redeclaring
    return change;
}
```

so change it to this:

```
public void MoneyGiven(int amount) {
        moneyGiven = amount; //assigning amount to moneyGiven
    }

    public int getChange() {

        change = moneyGiven - purchasePrice; //assigning values to change
        return change;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void MoneyGiven(int amount){
    int moneyGiven;
}
```

moneyGiven is not being initiated, so it is defaulted as 0. 
Change it to

```
int moneyGiven = amount;
```

and it should work. At the moment because moneyGiven = 0 (default value) and purchasePrice = 50, it then goes to

```
 public int getChange(){
    int change=moneyGiven-purchasePrice;
    return change;
}
```

So, 0 - 50 = 50
Hope this explains your problem.